# NSPredicate 'OR' filtering based on an NSArray of keys

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate, foundation

Consider the following NSArray:

```
NSArray *dataSet = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"abc", @"key1", @"def", @"key2", @"hij", @"key3", nil], 
                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"klm", @"key1", @"nop", @"key2", nil], 
                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"qrs", @"key2", @"tuv", @"key4", nil], 
                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"wxy", @"key3", nil], 
                 nil];
```

I am able to filter this array to find dictionary objects that contain the *key* `key1`

```
// Filter our dataSet to only contain dictionary objects with a key of 'key1'
NSString *key = @"key1";
NSPredicate *key1Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN self.@allKeys", key];
NSArray *filteretSet1 = [dataSet filteredArrayUsingPredicate:key1Predicate];
NSLog(@"filteretSet1: %@",filteretSet1);
```

Which appropriately returns:

```
filteretSet1: (
        {
        key1 = abc;
        key2 = def;
        key3 = hij;
    },
        {
        key1 = klm;
        key2 = nop;
    }
)
```

Now, I am wanting to filter the dataSet for dictionary objects containing *ANY* of the keys in an NSArray.

For example, using the array: `NSArray *keySet = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key1", @"key3", nil];` I want to create a predicate that returns and array of *any* dictionary objects that contain either 'key1' *or*  'key3' (ie. in this example all dictionary objects would be returned except for the third object - as it does not contain either 'key1' *or* 'key3').

Any ideas on how I would achieve this?  Would I have to use a compound predicate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ANY` operator of `NSPredicate` covers this:

```
NSSet *keys = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"key1", @"key3", nil];

NSPredicate *key1Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any self.@allKeys in %@", keys];
```

Comment: The *any* was what I was missing.  I don't know why I find NSPredicate so difficult to to get my head around.  Thanks for your answer.  Monolo +1 :)

Comment: is this case sensitive? I will find out eventually, but I hope it is already. Ill comment back later.

Comment: @coolcool1994 ANY and IN (and SELF) in the predicate above are not case sensitive (in fact I often write them in all caps to make them stand out), the key/method names are, so `@allKeys` _is_ case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
   NSString *key = @"key1";
   NSString *key1 = @"key3";
   NSPredicate *key1Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN self.@allKeys OR %@ IN self.@allKeys",key,key1];
   NSArray *filteretSet1 = [dataSet filteredArrayUsingPredicate:key1Predicate];
   NSLog(@"filteretSet1: %@",filteretSet1);
```

Works perfectly for me. Hope Helpful

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I am aware of being able to use OR.  The reason I wanted to use an array was for any number of keys rather than exactly 2 keys.

Answer (score 1):

Altough the question has been answered, you could also use block for more granularity:

```
NSArray *filter = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key1", @"key3",nil];

NSPredicate *filterBlock = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind){        
    NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary*)obj;

    // use 'filter' and implement your logic and return YES or NO
}];

[dataSet filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterBlock];
```

That could be rearranged as you want, maybe within its own method.