# NSPredicate using OR error

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

First time building an `NSPredicate`.

I would like to search a `managedobjectcontext` using this logic:

```
Search for a, grab all matches
Search for b, grab all matches, etc....

Nsarray *results = (has all a results, b results, etc);
```

My attempted predicate is:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name== %@ OR name == %@ OR name == %@",a,b,c];
```

However I get errors with this `predicate`...

Edited: Sample method I wrote

```
-(NSPredicate*)parsePartsIntoAPredicate:(NSMutableArray*)inputPartsNames{
    NSSet *keys=[NSSet setWithArray:inputPartsNames];
    NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any self.@name in %@", keys];
    NSLog(@"predicate = %@",predicate);
    return predicate;
}
```

Clarify:  I have a database of cars (20,000) Each car has multiple parts. I want to find all cars that have part a, and all cars that have part b, and all that have part c. Then I want to return an array with cars with part a,  b, c, etc...

If you think there is a better way let me know, but I am approaching this backwards. I am saying

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cars" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[self parsePartsIntoAPredicate:inputParts]];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *records = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear, have a look at this question and see the first answer [NSPredicate 'OR' filtering based on an NSArray of keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115377/nspredicate-or-filtering-based-on-an-nsarray-of-keys) and try to use it in your code

Comment: What error do you get? May be it's typo but"p" in "NSpredicate" should be capital.

Comment: try to make it more clear,helping without much information is bit risky!

Comment: To get helpful answers you have to show at least: 1) The definition of the managed object entity, 2) the exact predicate and fetch request (copy/paste without typos!), 3) the exact error message.

Comment: Sorry did it on iphone, will post from comp

Comment: What error do you get? Is `name` an attribute of the `Cars` entity? In that case try `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name IN %@", keys]`.

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY name IN %@", keys] (looks like it works, thanks), post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch all `Cars` objects that have a `name` which is one of the strings in the `keys` set or array, use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name IN %@", keys]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *key;
NSMutableArray *tempArray;
NSPredicate *searchForName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", key];
NSArray *filterArray = [tempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchForName];
NSLog(@"%@",filterArray);
```

Where **key** is your searchKeyword, **tempArray** is your CompleteArray in which data is present.

**Use Like this. Please put your data.**

Comment: is it faster to sort an existing array, or to put the predicate in a fetch request?  So in essence, would I ask coredata for ALL cars, then one by one find the cars that match each part?

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ '%@'", @"SELF contains[c] ",searchText]];
```

Comment: inputs have to be mutable... it could be 2 variables, could be 100.  Also would this do an OR?  So find all that have a, find all that have b, find all that have c, etc...